# What is the best way to add a scrollbar to a div for iPad and iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, html, scrollbar

Currently I am using a vertical scrollbar for a div when the contents are larger than the height of the div. This works great on Chrome, IE 7(!) and Firefox.

However, on IOS devices like iPad and iPhone there are no scrollbars for divs. What is the recommended solution? For simplicity, I want to run the same code on all platforms: Chrome, IE 7+, Firefox, iPhone and iPad.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there is an in-element scrollbar in iOS, it's just hidden until it's in use :( You use a two-finger drag to activate an element's scroll.

I don't think you can override the OS hiding the scrollbar, but `overflow-y: scroll;` in css is mostly likely what you want.

Comment: OK, the two finger thing works. Thanks. Next I'll try to force display of the scrollbar.

Comment: I implemented iScroll 4 (http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) which seems to be a well developed solution, but it didn't work because: 1. Broke default scrollbar functionality on Chrome. 2. The scrollbar did not display in the correct position on the page on iPad. I guess I need to change the CSS to make it work. In this case there may be separate CSS for IOS devices, which is not a good solution to me.

Comment: Have you tried making a specific css sheet for `media="mobile"` ? This will only be used for mobile devices. Otherwise you might try a css3 media query: http://www.css3.info/preview/media-queries/ Mobiles are usually pretty up-to-date, so they probably support much of css3.